# Why does OnDraw get called continuously on earlier Android versions?

Tags: java, android

While testing an app I have made on android version 2.3.4 OnDraw is called continouisly where as on 4.1.1 it works as intended.

I am still new to Android development so I am wondering what changed between versions to cause this and I am also trying to get my hands on more Android devices to see if it is happening with others.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't.  Something in your code is making onDraw get called.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but there isn't anything calling it. It works perfectly on 4.1 but not 2.3.4